# Fastest and efficient way to replace element and attribute value in an XML

Tags: java, regex, xml

I want to replace a value of an element and attribute of any XML. I have a list of replaceable elements and attributes. What is the most efficient and fastest way to do this? Using regex, `.*` is very expensive in performance and memory usage. Is there any way to minimize the usage of this in this requirement? So far, I have this.

For example, I have XMLs that contains the following (this sample is for explanation purposes only)

(1)

```
<Book>
    <author>Uncommon Passion</author>
    <title>Anne Calhoun</title>
</Book>
```

(2)

```
<Book author="Anne Calhoun">Uncommon Passion</Book>
```

(3)

```
<Article author="James Clear">Habit</Article>
```

Then I want to replace the value of the author element from xml 1 and at the same time the value of author attribute of xml 2 and 3. The incoming XMLs might have totally different tree-structure.

Comment: The safest and most standard conform way would be using an XSLT processor. And if you want to transform several elements/attributes at once, it would probably be the fastest, too.

Comment: You should not show code for this question. Show a list of attribute value's you want to find and in what tag (element), then show what you want to replace it with. Then I'll give you the regex template.

Comment: @sln: Are you sure that using RegEx'es on XML files is a good idea? Because usually it's not.

Comment: Regex is not right tool for irregular languages (more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747, and ofc https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). Consider using proper XML parser like Jsoup.

Comment: @zx485 - `Are you sure that using RegEx'es on XML files is a good idea? Because usually it's not` Yeah, I think the first level  _TAG_  parse, is not parsing SGML. Otherwise, the w3c specs wouldn't define tag parsing using pure regex. Dumb, Dummer, Dummest. All these people exist on the planet. https://regex101.com/r/4vjduH/1

Comment: @GraceDePaz - I have an appointment, you might have missed your chance for a solution today. I'll be here tomorrow briefly should you decide to comment...

Comment: @sln What about matching patterns that occur in comments and processing instructions?  What about `<&#78;ame>` instead of `<Name>`?  What about parsed entities?

Comment: Do not parse XML with regex.  Use a real XML parser.

Comment: @sln - sorry if i missed to emphasize that the solution im trying to do should cater any xml. Meaning, the tree structure might be different from one another. I updated my question. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, you can also parse and process XML using a language recognition tool such as [*ANTLR*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR).

Comment: `Then I want to replace the value of the author element from xml 1 and at the same time author attribute of xml 2` You mean the _value of the author attribute_ for number 2 I presume.

Comment: For number 2, the regex string and replacement string can be constructed dynamically. Using your example, it would be Find: `(<Book(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sauthor\s*=\s*)(?:(['"])([\S\s]*?)\2)((?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>)` Replace: `$1$2Peter Frampton$2$4` https://regex101.com/r/JjDWeG/1 Let me know if you want this for an answer that you accept.

Comment: @VGR - Unless you're looking for stuff inside _Comments or CDATA_, the idea is to _SKIP/FAIL_ these constructs. For Java, that means matching them. Ah, are you just learning xml or regex ?

Comment: @sln - that actually works if the element name is always Book. But, what if i have this `<Article author="James Clear">Habit</Article>`

Comment: @sln I look forward to seeing your regex for skipping comments, processing instructions, and CDATA sections.  As others keep trying to tell you, it can’t be done.  And I notice you didn’t cover parsed entities;  perhaps it is you who haven’t finished learning XML.  Even if it could be done, the regex would be a mess.  Grunt coders write code that works;  software engineers write code that works and is readable and maintainable.